# Add a preference to hide tag icons

Tags: feature-request, tags

I understand the tag icon is a kind of sponsorship.

However I'm suffering of a kind of attention disorder and the catchiness of some icons make me stay focused on them for some seconds before I can read the tag name and decide that I care or not about the tag (hint, most of the time, I don't). This happens even if I definitely know the icon (like Android). Also, this makes me *less* likely to click on questions with such icon tags because the questions with no tag icon make me more comfortable.

I don't know what the deals are in sponsorship, if the terms force Stack Overflow to show the icons to all users, but if that's not the case, it'd be really nice to have an option to hide the tag icon in the browsing pages (mostly the home page and search page).

By now some people would already have thought that I should add those tags on my "ignored tags" list, but I don't think that the option "ignored tags" helps me because if tomorrow my favorite tags get an icon or if I get an interest in a tag I used to ignore because of that, I'd still get the disturbance.

Comment: If you are that distracted by tiny, 16x16 icons, using the Internet must be very challenging for you. My sympathies.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you. Well, I avoid most sites like Reddit or Facebook and prefer news website with totally neutral visuals. Most of my news are gotten through peer sites like google news or news aggregators so I do with that. I aggressively support adblockers because of that. So it's not that challenging. The thing on SO is that there are about 50% of questions with icon tags in my lists. I can't make an easy rule for me like "I stop where things stand out" or "I stop where things don't stand out".

Comment: Does this make you nervous? http://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ewM.jpg If website designs affect you so much, you should learn a little javascript and make use of user scripts to customize your browsing experience.  Or perhaps turn off all images!  That would remove all distractions.

Comment: @Will EEEK! You should put a warning when linking such disturbing images like this ;-)

Comment: I notice them today in a horrible way. An entire page looked nice and normal except for one post that included `elasticsearch`, `logstash` and `kibana` that were lit up like a *Vegas-whorehouse*. Why a good informational/technical site like SO needs to do something like that is bewildering. Sometimes `KISS` is really the best philosophy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this very narrow use case should be implemented on the site itself, but you can add this simple userstyle in your browser to hide the icons:

```
.sponsor-tag-img {display:none;}
```

The easiest way to add this to your browser is by using [the Stylish extension](https://userstyles.org/), available for most browsers. There is a [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). You add it in the extension settings under "Manage styles".

You might want to restrict the style to only stackoverflow.com, like so:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://stackoverflow.com"), url-prefix("https://stackoverflow.com") {
  .sponsor-tag-img {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I can change the style with my F12 key (kind of Firebug), but I can't change for my entire browser, can I? I'm using Firefox if that's any indication.

Comment: Updated my answer with a complete example.

Comment: Well, I'm positively surprised. I didn't know this was possible. Thank you!

Comment: The best thing about this answer is that I too got rid of those icons now :-)

Comment: `@-moz-document url-prefix` no longer works in Firefox. But Stylish lets you restrict it by domain in the "Applies to" section anyway, so you can still do it.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to use an ad blocker to filter those images.

This rule will do the trick:

```
stackoverflow.com##IMG[class="sponsor-tag-img"]
```

You may want to remove the domain if you want the filter to work on other stack-exchange sites, as well. Or add separate rules for other SE sites.

Comment: Thank you! I prefer to keep adblock to exclusively block ads so I've personally chosen the other solution, but I tested this one and it also solves my problem. So you got my +1 ;)

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: if you mean AdBlock as a specific product - I recommend uBlock instead, or at least AdBlock Plus.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Edited to be a little more generic.

Comment: Double-Thank You, added to uBlock filter as AdBlock syntax rule and it worked like a charm.